# Postfix expression parser in Python

Tags: python, parsing, postfix-notation

I trying to complete my program but a running into a few things that I need help with. I need help trying to:
make sure my user input is correct and do an error test. Would i just do something like.....

```
if token == "" or token == " "
```

I am not sure how to make sure the user input is correct.

Assignment:

> Write a program (postfix.py) that extracts a postfix expression from
>   the user and evaluates it as described in class. Your program should
>   extract the expression from the user via standard input. The
>   expression should be formatted such that there is at least one blank
>   space between each operator and operand. For example,
>
> Enter a postfix expression: `5 6 * 13 2 * +` Assume all operators and operands are valid. The operands should be integer values while
>   the valid operators include `+ - / * %`
>
> After extracting the expression, use the `split()` method on the string
>   to split it into individual tokens that are stored in a Python list.
>   Note that a multi-digit operand (i.e. `13`) is considered a single
>   token.
>
> The postfix expression should be printed to standard output, one token
>   at a time, as it is being evaluated. In addition, if the expression is
>   valid, the result should be printed on the next line following the
>   expression as shown below
>
> ```
> 5 6 * 13 2 * +
> = 56
> ```
>
> If the expression is invalid, stop evaluating the expression once it
>   is determined there is an error and print 3 dollar signs. then print
>   an error message on the next line to indicate the error. For example,
>   if there are too many operators for the given operands encountered,
>   your program should produce the results shown below
>
> ```
> Enter a postfix expression: 17 6 / + 8 *
> 17 6 / + $$$
> Error: insufficient number of operands.
> ```
>
> When there are too few operators for the given operands, your program
>   should produce the results shown below
>
> ```
> Enter a postfix expression: 17 6 / 25 5 +
> 17 6 / 25 5 + $$$
> Error: insufficient number of operators.
> ```

My Code:

```
  input("Enter a postfix expression: ")
  operorList("*, /, -, +, %")

  def postfixEval(postfixExpr):
     operandStack = Stack()
     tokenList = postfixExpr.split()

     for token in tokenList:
        if token in "0123456789":
          operandStack.push(int(token))
     else:
        operand2 = operandStack.pop()
        operand1 = operandStack.pop()
        result = doMath(token,operand1,operand2)
        operandStack.push(result)
     return operandStack.pop()

 def doMath(op, op1, op2):
     if op == "*":
      return op1 * op2
     elif op == "/":
      return op1 / op2
     elif op == "+":
      return op1 + op2
     elif op == "%":
      return op1 % op2
     else:
      return op1 - op2
```

Comment: Just test whether the operator is in the operator list. If not, then it's invalid. For "too few operands", test whether the stack is empty when you need to pop from it. For "too few operators", test whether there's something left on the stack when you finish the loop.

Comment: @Barmar is this correct? if token.isdigit(): operandStack.push(int(token)) else: operand2 = operandStack.pop() operand1 = operandStack.pop() result = doMath(token,operand1,operand2) operandStack.push(result) except IndexError: if operandStack == Empty: print(result, "$$$") print("Error: Insufficient number of operators.") if len(operandStack) > 1: print (result, "$$$") print("Error: Insufficient number of operators.") return operandStack.pop(

Answer (score 0):

The assignmment tells that

> Assume all operators and operands are valid. The operands should be integer values while the valid operators include `+` `-` `/` `*` `%`

Thus one can assume that nothing else is input, and the only errors that happen are too many or not enough operands on the stack, so you would only need to test those.

---

The line

```
if token in "0123456789":
```

only checks if the whole token is a substring of `0123456789`, a.k.a a single digit, `01`, `4567` or so.

What you want to do instead is to check whether the token is all digits:

```
if token.isdigit():
    ...
```

---

As for the *too few operands*, either one of the `pop`s could throw an exception `IndexError`; you'd catch it and report an error:

```
try:
    operand2 = operandStack.pop()
    operand1 = operandStack.pop()        
except IndexError:
    # handle appropriately
```

Similarly too many operands would mean that the `operandStack` has more than 1 item at the end, so just check the `len(operandStack)`; if greater than 1 then report "too many operands".

Comment: 'if token.isdigit():
            operandStack.push(int(token))
        else:
            operand2 = operandStack.pop()
            operand1 = operandStack.pop()
            result = doMath(token,operand1,operand2)
            operandStack.push(result)
        except IndexError:
            if operandStack == Empty:
                print(result, "$$$")
                print("Error: Insufficient number of operators.")
            if len(operandStack) > 1:
                print (result, "$$$")
                print("Error: Insufficient number of operators.")
    return operandStack.pop()'

Comment: @lindsay Don't try to put code in comments, there's no formatting so it's very difficult to read. If you're having trouble getting it to work, add it as an addition to the question.